# Internal domain name different from website name

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2

I am not sure if this is the place where I should ask the question, but I'll give it a go.

I am learning to set up Microsoft Servers and I got a little bit curious of the set up I am trying to do.

So, my Active Directory domain is named `corp.footwear.com`. If I were to create a website for this little company called Footwear, should I use the website name `www.footwear.com`? My friend  told me that it's a bad practice to have similar names for active directory and website, but I'm not convinced. One recommended to have a separate website name, so I decided a website name called `www.shionneshoes.com`.

Basically, my question is that, if my active directory domain name is `corp.footwear.com`, should I use `www.footwear.com` for my website? And is it really a bad practice?

Comment: It makes no difference. The domain used for the website should the most ideal for marketing. If it happens to be similar to the AD domain, it doesn't matter.